# Get row where value is greatest

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query in SQL Server:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
D214.DESTIMATED,
D214.LINSEQNO,
H214.SHPID 
FROM IN_214_HDR H214
JOIN IN_214_DTL D214 ON H214.TRANNO = D214.TRANNO
WHERE H214.SHPID = 'NGB8264646'
```

It will return this result set

```
DESTIMATED                   LINSEQNO     SHPID
2014-08-24 00:00:00.000          1      NGB8264646
2014-09-09 00:00:00.000          2      NGB8264646
2014-09-09 00:00:00.000          3      NGB8264646
2014-09-23 00:00:00.000          4      NGB8264646
```

Using a different H214.SHPID I would get a different number of rows returned, they all will have a LINSEQNO = 1

```
DESTIMATED                   LINSEQNO     SHPID
2014-08-24 00:00:00.000          1      NGB8262321
2014-09-12 00:00:00.000          2      NGB8262321
2014-09-18 00:00:00.000          3      NGB8262321
2014-10-23 00:00:00.000          4      NGB8262321
2014-10-29 00:00:00.000          5      NGB8262321
2014-11-09 00:00:00.000          6      NGB8262321
```

What I need is a query which will return the same columns, but I only need the row where LINSEQ is greatest. So a result set like this is needed for each of these....

```
DESTIMATED                   LINSEQNO     SHPID
2014-09-23 00:00:00.000          4      NGB8264646
```

and

```
DESTIMATED                   LINSEQNO     SHPID
2014-11-09 00:00:00.000          6      NGB8264646
```

The min value of LINSEQNO will be 1 but the max could be anything > 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 D214.DESTIMATED,
             D214.LINSEQNO,
             H214.SHPID 
FROM IN_214_HDR H214
JOIN IN_214_DTL D214 ON H214.TRANNO = D214.TRANNO
WHERE H214.SHPID = 'NGB8264646'
ORDER BY LINSEQNO DESC
```

Comment: That was easy. Good simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select DESTIMATED, LINSEQNO, SHPID
from (select D214.DESTIMATED, D214.LINSEQNO, H214.SHPID,
             row_number() over (partition by H214.SHPID order by D214.LINSEQNO desc) as seqnum
      from IN_214_HDR H214 joi
           IN_214_DTL D214
           on H214.TRANNO = D214.TRANNO
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```